# Problem with cookies detection in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Here is the simple function that I'm using:

```
public function control() {
    $string = 'lolcheck';

    setcookie($string, $string, time() + 120, $this->path, $this->domain);

    if (isset($_COOKIE[ $string ])) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

The problem is that it only works when I open the page twice, because it gets the previously set cookie.

Apparently everyone suggest to use this practice, but its not working for me.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Unless you have specific reasons for using `setcookie`, you should be using `$_SESSION` instead and letting PHP juggle cookies for you.

Comment: @meagar Should I make a session just for cookie check?

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't be doing a cookie check at all. Just use `$_SESSION` and be done with it. It's safe to assume your users have cookies enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies do not work that way. When a cookie is set, it is not available (i.e. a corresponding `$_COOKIE` key exists) until the next request.

What actually happens is:

- client sends a requests
- server sends a response containing a *Set-Cookie* response header field

After that the client sends the cookie along with any following request:

- client sends a request containing a corresponding *Cookie* request header field
- server registers `$_COOKIE` key

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.

If you need it accessible on the same page, use sessions instead, or do a redirect to the same URL after the `setcookie` call.

Comment: Damn it I totally missed that part! How can I check if cookies are enabled then?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are set / received as part of http headers exchange, so, under usual circumstances are one of the first thing the client (browser) sends / receives. For your problem, the client only knows it's got a cookie to send on the second request.

Using a good Firefox extension like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) can help you discover which stuff's sent when.