# Test for cookies in PHP

Tags: php

What is the best way to tell if someone has cookies enabled in their browser.  I tried:

```
<?php

        setcookie('cookies','yes',time()+7200);
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookies'])) {
        echo '<div class="error" style="float:right;">You must enable cookies and Javascript to use this site.</div>';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }


?>
```

but sometimes it displays the alert even if cookies are enabled.  I only want an alert if cookies are NOT enabled.

Comment: Cookies do not work that way. See [Problem with cookies detection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563819/problem-with-cookies-detection-in-php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't work is because cookies are sent with the request. The code you're trying will work, but `setcookie` has to be in a different request than the `isset` call. Try calling a redirect in between calling those 2 functions.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without a redirect?  Maybe another approach?

Comment: Nope. You will need to make at least 2 request to check.

Comment: @shummel7845: no, the cookies have to be transmitted.

Comment: the only way would probably be JavaScript in this case

Answer (score 2):

It is because your cookies are set at the same time as your request is sent to the browser.
It means that even if setcookie() is executed **before** the script ends the cookies are set **after** the browser received the request.

To do in a such way, you would need to redirect to a page with a trivial argument and then check for cookies.

A more flexible solution would be to check in javascript.